# KSQL failed to create stream from topic

Tags: ksqldb

have a json topic name "customer-event" and trying to create stream from the below KSQL:

```
create stream cssc_customer_event_json (description varchar,pageEvent_id varchar)with (kafka_topic='customer-event', value_format='json');
```

it return below message:

```
 Message
------------------------------------
 Statement written to command topic
------------------------------------
```

after the query run and no stream has been created. Anyone can advise what may be the problem?

Thanks

Regards,
Han

Same thing happens when I try to create table.

```
create stream cssc_customer_event_json (reportSuite varchar,exclude_id varchar,exclude_value varchar,exclude_description varchar,pageEvent_id varchar)with (kafka_topic='customer-event', value_format='json');
```

it should create a new stream. But it has no stream created

```
ksql> show streams;

 Stream Name | Kafka Topic | Format
------------------------------------
------------------------------------
```

Comment: What version of KSQL are you running? Are there any errors in the KSQL Server log?

Comment: Hi Robin, we are using KSQL 5.0.0. but I don't have access to the KSQL server log. Is this possibly a configuration error? thanks

Comment: To understand what's happened here, whether it's a problem in your data, or your configuration, you're going to need the KSQL server log.

Answer (score 0):

The message:

```
Statement written to command topic
```

Is generally only seen when the REST endpoints thread writes the message to the command topic, then times out waiting from the engine side to read the message and process it.

There are a couple of reasons this can occur:

1. There's a misconfiguration in Kafka stopping the engine side reading, e.g. ACLs set incorrectly, so ksqlDB can write, but can't read the data.
2. There's a stability issue in Kafka - e.g. endangered partitions etc, though this *tends* to stop the write to Kafka working, not the read side.
3. The thread reading the command topic has crashed.  There were some bugs in earlier versions that could cause this.  The ksql application log would report this. Restarting may fix it, or upgrading.
4. The thread reading the command topic is stuck. There were some bugs in earlier versions that could cause this.  The ksql application log would NOT report this. You'd need to do a thread-dump or similar to diagnose. Restarting may fix it, or upgrading.